# How to get Anchor Property from an anchorpane to do some binding or animations?

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I am trying to get anchorpane `leftAnchorProperty` to create a new `KeyValue` but it is not working.

My code:

```
Animation a = new Timeline( new KeyFrame(
Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(MyAPane.leftAnchorProperty(child), 10)
));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share more of your code so we can see how you are trying to use that?

Comment: Sure,  I'm  doing some editing.

Comment: I suppose you want to know the position of your `Node` inside the Layout (`AnchorPane`) ? If it is the case concentrate on the layout property (layoutx/y) or local bounds of the node itself and not that of the container !

Comment: This not about setLayoutX, Y methods. This is about anchorpane constraints.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to use getProperties method(inherits from node)  to get anchorpane  constraints as double properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such property since the value is stored in the `properties` `ObservableMap`. (The value is stored there, since only children of a `AnchorPane` need it, but there are other layouts a `Node` can be added to.)

However in your case you only need a `WritableValue`, which you can easily implement yourself:

```
WritableValue<Double> writable = new WritableValue<Double>() {

    @Override
    public Double getValue() {
        return AnchorPane.getLeftAnchor(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Double value) {
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(child, value);
    }

};

// a starting value for the animation is important, since otherwise interpolation won't work
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(child, 0d);
```

Consider using the `translateX` property though. This would be simpler...

Comment: Do you mind if I asked you to give more information about Writable Value,  do they slower than simpleXXXXProperties etc

Comment: It's just an interface that is used here... it usually contains the methods for getting or setting the property, if implemented by the property itself: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WritableValue.html However this is the only way to do this without using private members of `AnchorPane`, like the key of the value in the map.

Comment: What about performance with respect to well known properties?

Comment: Of course it's less performant, since it's stored in a `Map` and therefore a lookup is needed instead of simply writing to a field of the property object. It shouldn't be necessary to optimize this though, since it should only be executed once per frame ([YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it))... If you want a better performance, set the `managed` property of `child` to `false` and modify `layoutX`, `layoutY`, `width` and `height` yourself the way `AnchorPane` would do it...

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you!

Comment: In my case, it was better to use the translateX property.